# Fetching records from SQL based on Month name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

[image]
So this my table structure and data.

Now I want to filter data based on Month by ExpenseDate column.
So how can I achieve that?
I was trying

> select * from tblExpenses where (ExpenseDate = MONTH('April'))

But it throws an error: "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."
Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting `month()` on the wrong column.  It can be applied to `ExpensesDate`:

```
select *
from tblExpenses
where month(ExpenseDate) = 4;
```

Note that `month()` returns a number, not the name of the month.

I think it is more likely that you want records from a particular *April*, not *every* April.  This would be expressed as:

```
where ExpenseDate >= '2018-04-01' and ExpenseDate < '2018-05-01'
```

Comment: Please add that this expression `month(ExpenseDate) = 4;` is not SARGable plus does not handle multiple years.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon It was very quick. You saved a lot of my time. Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

I think your where clause is just reversed I think you want this (and change the word to a number)

```
select * from tblExpenses where Month(ExpenseDate) = 4
```

Comment: Yeah, @Brad I got it. Thanks.